# Magento how to getLinkFile()

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I want to have in a function the link_file field of table downloadable_link in Magento DB

[image: Table]

I tried with `$_prodId  = $this->getProduct()->getLinkFile();` to get the LinkFile of the current product , but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $table = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link');
    $collection = $table->getCollection()->addProductToFilter($product_id);
    foreach ($collection as $downloadable){
       echo $downloadable->getLinkFile();
    }
?>
```

So you will have only the first record found.

```
<?php
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    if ($product->getTypeId() == 'downloadable') {
        $table = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link');
        $collection = $table->getCollection()->addProductToFilter($product->getId());
        foreach ($collection as $downloadable){         
           $linkFile = $downloadable->getLinkFile();
           break;           
        }
        echo $linkFile;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but im looking for without collection. Do you have any idea?

Comment: does not have a direct way, even consulting via direct sql, can have more than one record, this table is for this, have 1 or amusement download by product.

Comment: You need to analyze what really you want to do with this data, it is possible you take the first position of the collection but it is wrong.

Comment: I just want to have in a variable the value of link_file for the current product

Comment: You are Genius ! Dexxtz this is exactly what i was looking for you save hours of investigation

Comment: You need to confirm that my answer is right, contrary your question it is open.

Comment: At the beginning of my answer left is 0, below it has a visa, he gotta be green for to your question is finished.